# Ant design: Wrapping a menu item into a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm playing around with ant-design and trying to structure a simple menu, and everything works as expected:

```
<Menu mode="inline">
  <Menu.Item key="/">
    <Icon type="dashboard" theme="outlined" />
    Dashboard
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="/transactions">
    <Icon type="bars" theme="outlined" />
    Transactions
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="/groups">
    <Icon type="team" theme="outlined" />
    Groups
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="/account">
    <Icon type="idcard" theme="outlined" />
    Account
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

(https://codesandbox.io/s/wqn37ojmv7)

Now, I wanted to DRY up this code a bit, by making a separate wrapped `MenuItem` component:

```
const MenuItem = ({route, icon, children}) => (
  <Menu.Item key={route}>
    <Icon type={icon} theme="outlined" />
    {children}
  </Menu.Item>
);

// ...
<Menu mode="inline">
  <MenuItem route="/" icon="dashboard">Dashboard</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem route="/transactions" icon="bars">Transactions</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem route="/groups" icon="team">Groups</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem route="/account" icon="idcard">Account</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

However, substituting my shiny new component will pretty much break everything - somehow I seem to lose some props that were magically passed to the `Menu.Item`s before (like a `clsPrefix` or a `onItemHover`-callback): https://codesandbox.io/s/ojyqy0oqq6

What is going on here? How are these props passed behind the scenes and how can I wrap `Menu.Item` correctly without losing all of this magic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could pass the rest of the passed props

```
const MenuItem = ({route, icon, children, ...props}) => ( 
    <Menu.Item key={route} {...props}> 
        <Icon type={icon} theme="outlined" />
        {children}
    </Menu.Item> );
```